# Extra White Space on Wordpress website To the right side on mobile view

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

When open in mobile view there is extra white space to the right side . Desktop view is ok but i am having problem with mobile view . kindly help ....

Remove all negative margin .
website uses 100% full Width container size .
The overflow is hidden .

Comment: I don't see any white space issues on mobile. If this is still a problem, please provide more details on where you see the extra white space.

Comment: Yes I corrected it . but there is another page having that same issue !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.elementor-441 .elementor-element.elementor-element-39c3d4e.e-con {
    --flex-grow: 0;
    --flex-shrink: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Margin: auto; is what fixes it.

Comment: do i have to put this code on site settings customs css ?

Comment: That all depends on how your site is set up. Wherever you can add custom css, try adding the margin: auto; to the css selector.